# Complete Newbie: Axiom of Foundation Exercise

Tags: set-theory

No other axioms. There are $3$ sets such that:

$x\in y$;
$y\in z$;
$z\in x$;

These sets violate foundation.

I don't get it... For $x$, $z\in x$, so z must be the $\epsilon$-minimal member but the only member of $z$ is $y$.

$z \cap x = \{y\}\cap\{z\} = \emptyset$. None of the members of $z$ (only $y$) are members of $x$ so doesn't that satisfy definition of Foundation?

Please help this noob, thanks

Comment: $x\epsilon y $means $x$ is a proper subset of $y$?

Comment: What makes you think that $y$ is the **only** member of $z$?

Comment: It is impossible to prove with only Extensionality and Foundation. The set $\{x, y, z\}$ with the relation $E=\{(x, z), (z, y), (y, x)\}$ gives a structure satisfying both Extensionality and Foundation. The solution given by @drhab is correct.

Comment: You did not say that $z$ is the only member of $x$ so you can't tell whether  $z$ is a $\in$-minimal member of $x.$

Comment: @johndoe No, an **element of**.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to find an $\epsilon$-minimal member of set $\{x,y,z\}$.

edit: the comment of **Asaf** on your question made me decide to undelete this answer.

Comment: Where did this set {x,y,z} come from?

Comment: By application of axioms PAIR and SUM. Is it forbidden to use them here ("no other axioms")? If so then this is not a good hint.

Comment: Please assume no other axioms. This exercise problem only came after Extensionality and Foundation.

Comment: Part of the reason I pinged you is that you can undelete your answer!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for pinging.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct: these sets do not violate Foundation, if you have no other assumptions about the sets that exist and no other axioms. 
 Probably whoever posed the problem intended you to assume additional axioms so that you can say $\{x,y,z\}$ is a set as well which then has no $\in$-minimal element.